# What is the difference between a desktop environment and a shell?

Tags: desktop-environments, environment-variables

I may be asking a basic question for many of you.

What is exactly linux environment ? and what the relation between linux environment and shell? and what the relation between linux environment and running processes?

Sorry if my question makes no sense !

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "Linux environment" you mean environment variables?

Env vars are local to every shell - so if you set one in one terminal window it will not show up in another. Child processes will inherit a copy of their parent's environment, so if you set particular variables and then start a program, that program will see those variables, too - but neither parent nor child can change the other's variables.

Does that answer your question?